# how to split file lines based on comma and concatenate new string

Tags: python

I have a file which has lines like below,
Files are in /tmp/file

```
            cat /tmp/file
            server1,server2
            server4,server4
```

I want to concatenate each line to new word ".com" so it will look like below.
When i covert this and split it doesn't work , Please guide

```
        newfile = server1.com,server2.com
                  server3.com,server4.com



            with open('/tmp/file', 'r') as file1:
                   newline = ''
                   for line in file1:
                       y = line.split()
                       print(y)
                   for line in y:
                       z = str(y).split(',')
                       print(z)
                       newline = str(z)+".com".join('' )
                   print(newline)
```

Results :

```
            ['server1,server2']
            ['server3,server4']
            ["['server3", "server4']"]
            ["['server3", "server4']"]
```

Expected :
                server1.com,server2.com
                server3.com,server4.com

Comment: `','.join([f"{j}.com" for i in p.read_text().splitlines() for j in i.split(',')])`(where `p` is `pathlib.Path` object.)

Comment: Please add explanation . This seems not working.                                                                                        ','.join([f"{j}.com" for i in p.read_text().splitlines() for j in i.split(',')])
  File "<ipython-input-100-f0280c232ed5>", line 1
    ','.join([f"{j}.com" for i in p.read_text().splitlines() for j in i.split(',')])
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: Python3 , I do have 2.7 as well. In [110]:                                                        
 with open('/tmp/file', 'r') as file1:
     ...:     for i in file1.read().splitlines():
     ...:         print(i)
     ...:         for j in i.split(','):
     ...:             k = j.splitlines()
     ...:             abc = ",".join([k+".com"])
     ...:             print(abc)                                                                                                                        Error:   TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('/tmp/file', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        newline = line.strip()
        newline = newline.split(',')
        for i in range(len(newline)):
            newline[i] = newline[i] + ".com"
        newline = ",".join(newline)
        print newline
```

This code can be optimized a lot. But this is for better understanding